# Что означает код ошибки 200?

Tags: laravel, apache, http

Помогите разобраться, нигде не могу найти информацию.

Comment: Гляньте тут: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27921537/returning-http-200-ok-with-error-within-response-body

Answer (score 4):

Код `200` не код ошибки, это значит что *всё в порядке* - клиентом запрошены  данные в заголовке и/или теле сообщения (ответа на запрось).

Для списка всех возможных кодов см. например [HTTP Status Codes](https://www.restapitutorial.com/httpstatuscodes.html) или на русском [Список кодов состояния HTTP](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_HTTP).